# Componente filho chamando método de outro componente filho

Tags: angular, typescript

Eu tenho 3 components, um component A Pai, B Filho e um C Filho.

```
export class A Parent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { 
  }    
}
```

No component B, eu tenho um método para criar usuário:

```
export class B Parent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { 
}

create() {
    this.userService.create()
      .subscribe((res) => { 
        // Call other method in Component C
        //this.card.emit(null)  
      }); 
  } 

 }
```

E agora, eu tenho um component, onde eu preciso chamar o método da lista:

```
export class C Parent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { 
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getUsers();
}
    
getUSers() {
    this.userService.getUsers()
         .subscribe((res) => {  
            this.users = res
          }); 
    } 
     
}
```

E aqui, a minha view:

```
  <div class="col s6">
    <list-administrators ></list-administrators>
  </div>

  <div class="col s6" *ngIf="card == 'create'">
    <create-administrator></create-administrator>
  </div>

  <div class="col s6" *ngIf="card == 'details'">
    <details-administrator></details-administrator>
  </div>

  <div class="col s6" *ngIf="card == 'edit'">
    <edit-administrator></edit-administrator>
  </div>
```

No componente B, eu tenho um método para criar um usuário. Quando ele criar, gostaria de chamar a listagem do outro filho C. Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Não sei te responder se está a melhor forma para fazer isso.
Porém o que você poderia fazer é.
A - (Pai)
B - (Filho)
C - (Filho)

-> então o Html deve ser algo parecido com isso:

```
<a>
<b (outputEmit)="emitted()" ></b>
<c #componentC></c>
</a>
```

No controller da A você pode declarar um evento e receber a emissão de criação no componente B, executando uma ação no controller C.

```
export class A
@ViewChild('componentC') componentCElement: ElementRef;

emitted() {
    this.componentCElement.MethodQueQuerExecutar();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado Renan Degrandi, eu acabei utilizando um service, compartilhar os dados com outros componentes é bem mais eficiente, pois não precisaria criar códigos repetidos, então, compartilhando .....:
Service
    export class EventsService {

```
  teste = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

 constructor() { }

 getEvent(event: any) {
   this.teste.emit(event);
 }

}
```

Com isto posso trocar dados com outros components em tempo de execução, agora o component B
Component B
    create() {
        this.userService.create()
          .subscribe((res) => {
            ...
            this.eventService.getEvent(true);
          }); 
    }

desta forma envio para lá um valor qualquer ou objeto desejável e agora, no meu caso, eu posso fazer a verificação deste valor e se for verdadeiro no component C, eu chamo o ngOnInit do component C para fazer novamente a listagem dos dados que eu queria, desta forma ......
Component C
    ngOnInit() {
        this.eventService.card.subscribe((res) => {
          if(res)
          this.getUsers();
        })
        this.getUsers();
    }